# Running out of real memory in Java

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory, ram

I am trying to do image processing with multiply (4) camera. My code works but if I let it run for more then a few minutes I get an error saying that I have run out of memory. I am monitoring my RAM and I can see that I am using more and more as the program runs. 
I have read a lot and have tried to change the size of the heap and the JVM memory. This helped a little but it still crashes.
Can someone please help me?
Here is my code:

cameraCaller

```
//This class opens and displays cameras 
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorExtractor;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.video.BackgroundSubtractor;

public class cameraCaller
{

    /** 
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);


        //open up the cameras
        VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
        VideoCapture camera2 = new VideoCapture(2);
        //VideoCapture camera3 = new VideoCapture(3);
        //VideoCapture camera2 = new VideoCapture("http://192.168.0.7/VIDEO.CGI?.mjpg");

        //Make all the camera windows and cams 


        //Camera 1 
        Cam cam = new Cam(camera);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.add(cam);
        frame.setSize(800,800);  
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //Camera 2 
        Cam cam2 = new Cam(camera2);
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame2.add(cam2);
        frame2.setSize(800,800);    
        frame2.setVisible(true);

        //Camera 3 
        /*
        Cam cam3 = new Cam(camera3);
        JFrame frame3 = new JFrame();
        frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame3.add(cam3);
        frame3.setSize(800,800);    
        frame3.setVisible(true);
        */


        //Update the windows while the cameras are open 

        while( camera2.isOpened() && camera.isOpened())// && camera3.isOpened() )
        {
            cam.repaint();
            cam2.repaint();
            //cam3.repaint();


        }


    }

}
```

Cam

```
//this calls process a feed from a camera 
//takes in a a OPENCV 'VideoCapture' object and processes it the feed. 
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfDMatch;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfKeyPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorExtractor;
import org.opencv.features2d.DescriptorMatcher;
import org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Cam extends JPanel
{
    VideoCapture cam;
    boolean start;
    Mat bg;
    Mat last;
    Mat bw;
    FeatureDetector detector;
    DescriptorExtractor extractor;
    MatOfKeyPoint ball01Points;
    DescriptorMatcher match; 
    Mat ball01Descriptor;
    Mat orginal;
    public Cam(VideoCapture camera)
    {

        cam = camera;
        start = true;
        bg = new Mat();
        last = new Mat();
        bw = new Mat();
        BufferedImage ball01 = null;
        detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
        extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SURF);
        match = DescriptorMatcher.create( DescriptorMatcher.FLANNBASED );
        ball01Points = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        ball01Descriptor = new Mat();


        /*
         * Testing object reconition
        File ball01File = new File("ball01.jpg" );
        try
        {
            ball01 = ImageIO.read(ball01File);  

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        //detector.detect(Buff2Mat(ball01), ball01Points);
        //extractor.compute(Buff2Mat(ball01), ball01Points, ball01Descriptor);

        //  System.out.println(ball01Descriptor.size());
        */

    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        super.paintComponent(g);
        //Mats need for image processing
        Mat orginal = new Mat();
        Mat current = new Mat();
        Mat grey = new Mat();
        Mat blur = new Mat();
        Mat temp = new Mat();
        Mat sub = new Mat();
        Mat sub2 = new Mat();
        Mat thresh = new Mat();
        Mat thresh2 = new Mat();
        Mat canny = new Mat();
        Mat erode = new Mat();
        Mat dilate = new Mat();
        Mat blur2 = new Mat();
        Mat blur3 = new Mat();

        //Array list to hold location rectangle 
        ArrayList<Rect> array = new ArrayList<Rect>();
        //System.out.println(start);


        //Get the background to  subtract out. 
        if( start )
        {
            start = false; 
            cam.read(bg);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(bg,bg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
            Imgproc.equalizeHist(bg,bg);
            Imgproc.GaussianBlur(bg, bg,new Size(5,5), 3);
            Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold( bg,bg,255,Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV,5,2);
            last = bg.clone();


        }
        //set start flage to false
        start = false; 

        //get current image
        cam.read(current);
        orginal = current.clone();

        //turn the image grey, then blur
        Imgproc.cvtColor(current,grey, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(grey, blur,new Size(5,5), 50);

        /*
         * Image recognition testing

        Find the Key points
        MatOfKeyPoint points = new MatOfKeyPoint();
        Mat descriptor = new Mat();
        detector.detect(grey, points);
        temp = grey.clone();
        extractor.compute(temp, points, descriptor);

         Match the key points
         List<MatOfDMatch> matchedPoints = new ArrayList<MatOfDMatch>() ;
         match.knnMatch(descriptor, ball01Descriptor ,matchedPoints,3);

         System.out.println(matchedPoints.size());
        */

        //Thresh the image
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold( blur,thresh,255,Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV,5,2);

        //Subtract the base frame and the last frame
        Core.subtract(thresh, bg, sub);
        Core.subtract(sub, last, sub2);
        last = blur.clone();

        //reblur the image
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(sub2, blur2,new Size(5,5), 50);

        //dilate then erode
        Imgproc.dilate(blur2, dilate,Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(2,2))); 
        Imgproc.erode(dilate, erode,Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(2,2))); 

        //Thresh the image again. 
        Imgproc.threshold(erode, thresh2 , 100,255,Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);

        //find the edges 
        Imgproc.Canny(thresh2, canny, 200, 300,5, start );

        //Blur the image again
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(canny, blur3,new Size(5,5), 250);


        //Get the rectangle to put around the objects
        array = detection_contours(blur3);

        //Draw the rectangle on the image
        if (array.size() > 0) 
        {

            Iterator<Rect> it2 = array.iterator();

            while (it2.hasNext())
            {
                Rect obj = it2.next();
                Core.rectangle(orginal, obj.br(), obj.tl(),
                        new Scalar(255, 255, 255), 5);
            }

        }


        //convert the imaeg
        BufferedImage image = Mat2Buff(orginal);
        //BufferedImage image = Mat2Buff(blur3);
        //update the image
        g.drawImage(image,10,10,image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(), null);

    }

    //convert  a mat to a buff
    public static BufferedImage Mat2Buff(Mat m)
    {

        int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY;
        if (m.channels() > 1)
        {
            type = BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR;
        }
        int bufferSize = m.channels() * m.cols() * m.rows();
        byte[] b = new byte[bufferSize];
        m.get(0, 0, b); // get all the pixels
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(m.cols(), m.rows(), type);
        final byte[] targetPixels = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        System.arraycopy(b, 0, targetPixels, 0, b.length);
        return img;


    }

    //convert  a buff 2 a mat
    public static Mat Buff2Mat(BufferedImage image)
    {
        byte[] data = ((DataBufferByte) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        Mat mat = new Mat(image.getHeight(), image.getWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
        mat.put(0, 0, data);
        return mat;

    }

    //get the rectangles to draw in image
    //use this to calibrate the size change
    public static ArrayList<Rect> detection_contours(Mat outmat)
    {
        Mat v = new Mat();
        Mat vv = outmat.clone();
        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(vv, contours, v,  Imgproc.RETR_CCOMP, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        //Change this numbers
        double maxArea = 50000;
        double minArea = 1000;
        int maxAreaIdx = -1;
        //Rect r = null;
        ArrayList<Rect> rect_array = new ArrayList<Rect>();

        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) 
        {
            Mat contour = contours.get(i);
            double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(contour);
            maxAreaIdx = i;
            if( Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)) < maxArea  &&  Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(i)) > minArea )
            {
                rect_array.add( Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(maxAreaIdx)));
            }

        }

        return rect_array;

    }

    //image recognition, find similar areas 
    private ArrayList<Rect> getRects(Mat img)
    {

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        List<MatOfPoint> edges = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(img, contours, new Mat(),  Imgproc.RETR_CCOMP, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        //Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contours, edges, TOP_ALIGNMENT, isEnabled()));



        return null;
    }



    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you tight-looping in your `main` method, calling `repaint()` continuously?

Comment: I started attempting to clean up the code you dumped, but it's just an awful lot of wasted space that no one wants to read through and I gave up half way through. You've made absolutely no effort in making it readable, I suggest you try to improve it a little (and split it in to different code chunks for different classes) if you want people to take the time to look through it for you.

Comment: I cleaned up my code. I had in different classes. I did not post it in different blocks

Answer (score 0):

There is a profiling tool included in the `\bin` directory of JDK called `jvisualvm`, which you can use to monitor your memory and CPU usage, among other things. You may find it useful, and can find further info about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html).